# Android Studio can't find node:6.7.0. Mac mini M1

Tags: android, node.js, macos, android-studio

I am having a problem getting Android Studio to build a project on the M1 Mac mini. It gives back the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:nodeSetup'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:detachedConfiguration3'.
   > Could not find org.nodejs:node:6.7.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/nodejs/node/6.7.0/node-6.7.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/nodejs/node/6.7.0/node-6.7.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/nodejs/node/6.7.0/node-6.7.0.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/org/nodejs/node/6.7.0/node-6.7.0.pom
       - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/nodejs/node/6.7.0/node-6.7.0.pom
       - https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.7.0/node-v6.7.0-darwin-arm64.tar.gz
     Required by:
         project :app
```

Node is installed and the Path is set. For me it looks like a dependency error, but I can not find where it is. Also online I could find any solutions to this.
If someone is around, that could help, that'd be awesome, I speeded now hours trying to fix this :)

Comment: node 6 is ANCIENT.  It's possible there isn't an M1/ARM binary for it.  It's been end-of-life since May 2019.

Comment: Did u find any solution for this? Nothing seems to be working for me.

Comment: You can manually download it from here: https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.7.0/

Comment: @kandroidj where to place it after downloading it from the link?

Answer (score 1):

As Joe said node 6.7.0 is too old.
Try to add node version as below.

```
android {
    node {
        version = "16.2.0"
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this solution by adding it on app build.gradle but not working for me? Go the same error with the update version like - Could not find org.nodejs:node:16.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Add the following node version to build.gradle (including submodule)

   android {
   node {
   version = "16.2.0"
   }
   }
2. Invalidate Cache and restart
3. Clean build.

These steps worked for me on Android Studio Arctic Fox Patch 4.

Also, downgrading studio to version 4.1.1 solved this issue for me without adding the node version.

Comment: I have tried this solution by adding it on app build.gradle but not working for me? Do I need to do it on any other place?